# pbinom function gets error when using readline()

Tags: r

I try to prompt user to enter "n" value but I get an error saying:

> Error in pbinom(s[i], n, p) :  
>   Non-numeric argument to
>   mathematical function

If I set n= anynumber directly, the function will work perfectly. What is the problem here?

```
n = readline("please enter an integer n:")
p = seq(from = 0.05, to = 1,by=0.05)
s = seq(from = 0, to = n)
M <- matrix(0, ncol=length(p), nrow=length(s), dimnames=list(s, p))
for(i in seq_along(s)){
  M[i, ] <- pbinom(s[i], n, p)
}
print(round(M,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your problem. All you need to do is change the first line:

```
n = as.numeric(readline("please enter an integer n:"))
```

If you check the value of n in your original code with readline using the class() or str() function, you discover that it's a character, even though you you inputted a number. If you've ever programmed in a variant of the C language you would know that you need to declare your variable types. readline() seems to default to character strings, so you just coerce it to a numeric variable type. You can't do math with characters, only with numbers. So all I did was change the class of the variable taken in from standard input.

Again, the way you had it checking the class or structure returns character.

```
 > class(n)
[1] "character"
```

The way I have it returns numeric:

```
> class(n)
[1] "numeric"
```

Try calculating n + 1 with both cases. See what happens.

Comment: When I try numeric, I was not allowed to enter input and still get errors

Comment: I don't get it. I've copied and pasted your code into an R script and sourced it and it works fine. Are you doing numeric() or as.numeric()? There is a difference.

Comment: n = as.numeric(readline("please enter an integer n:"))


p = seq(from = 0.05, to = 1,by=0.05)
s = seq(from = 0, to = n)

M <- matrix(0, ncol=length(p), nrow=length(s), dimnames=list(s, p))


for(i in seq_along(s)){
  
  M[i, ] <- pbinom(s[i], n, p)
  
}

print(round(M,3))



This is what I have. When I run the code, the console does not ask me to input n

Comment: Hmm, I am running the code in Rstudio. Maybe that makes a difference. Something to think about. It also works in the default RGui in windows. How are you running your code? With Rscript or R --vanilla?